# What does "Fehlbelegungsabgabe" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does "Fehlbelegungsabgabe" mean?

I didn't find a definition anywhere, I just found a Wikipedia page: [Here](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fehlbelegungsabgabe)

Comment: You link to Wikipedia, where you can read a detailed explanation, and then ask us here? What do you expect of us? That we add more information? That we translate it into other languages? What?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Bureaucratic language even in the mild extent used by Wikipedia to explain the term is difficult to understand even for advanced learners. The vast majority of what I read and write is in English and yet I find it at time difficult to understand such texts, even if they are written for human readers (i.e., not lawyers).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Wikipedia-page](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fehlbelegungsabgabe) explains it in detail.

The word is combined by three parts Fehl-belegung-abgabe.
**Fehl** is related to **Fehler** (error). **Belegung** is occupancy, **Abgabe** is a fee.

In Germany exist appartments for people with no/low income. The rent is very low.

It can happen, that you live in such an apartment and you find a new job with a higher salary. So you earn too much to have the right to live in the apartment. You can still stay in the apartment, but you have to pay this **Fehlbelegungsabgabe**. It is the fee to pay, because your occupancy in this subsidized apartment is not correct.